# "Красивое" размещение данных. Qt Designer

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qlayout, qgridlayout

Так должен выглядеть интерфейс. При изменении размера окна, размер окон с данными тоже должен меняться, кроме среднего (фиксированный размер).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое, что приходит на ум - использовать `QTablewidget` или `QTableView`, но у них размер ячеек не изменяется при изменении размера окна (или я не нашел как). 
Решил использовать `QTextEdit`, а потом как-то допилить внешний вид.

Поведение окна, что описывается кодом снизу, полностью устраивает:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(243, 168)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.textEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.textEdit_9.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.textEdit_7.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_7.setFixedSize(45, 148)
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.splitter_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.textEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.textEdit_8.setText("TEXT")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit_8)
        self.textEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.textEdit_10.setText("111")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit_10)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.splitter_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при добавлении дополнительных окон "красота" пропадает и нарушается положение верхних `QTexEdit`относительно нижних. При увеличении размеров окна все`QTextEdit` опять выравниваются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(465, 166)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.textEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter)
        self.textEdit_11.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_11.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(214, 0))
        self.textEdit_11.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 80))
        self.textEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter)
        self.textEdit_12.setText("TEXT")
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit_12.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit_12.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textEdit_12.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 80))
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.splitter)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.textEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.textEdit_13.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_13.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_13)
        self.textEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.textEdit_14.setText("111")
        self.textEdit_14.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_14)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.textEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.textEdit_9.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_9.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(214, 0))
        self.textEdit_9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 80))
        self.textEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.splitter_2)
        self.textEdit_7.setText("TEXT")
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit_7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit_7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textEdit_7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 80))
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.splitter_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.textEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget1)
        self.textEdit_8.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit_8)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.textEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget1)
        self.textEdit_10.setText("111")
        self.textEdit_10.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_10)
        self.textEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget1)
        self.textEdit_15.setText("111")
        self.textEdit_15.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_15)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.splitter_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

Тоже не нашел как исправить подобное расхождение и перешел на `QGridLayout`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(465, 168)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.textEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_11.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_11.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(214, 0))
        self.textEdit_11.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 80))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_11, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        self.textEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_12.setText("TEXT")
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit_12.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit_12.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textEdit_12.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 80))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_12, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.textEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_13.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_13.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_13, 0, 2, 1, 2)
        self.textEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_14.setText("111")
        self.textEdit_14.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_14, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        self.textEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_9.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_9.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(214, 0))
        self.textEdit_9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 80))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_9, 2, 0, 2, 1)
        self.textEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_7.setText("TEXT")
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit_7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit_7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textEdit_7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 80))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_7, 2, 1, 2, 1)
        self.textEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_8.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_8, 2, 2, 1, 2)
        self.textEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_10.setText("111")
        self.textEdit_10.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_10, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.textEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_15.setText("111")
        self.textEdit_15.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_15, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

Но с `QGridLayout` другая проблема. При увеличении окна, `QTextEdit` увеличиваются непропорционально друг другу. Выделенная область растягивается сильнее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли реализовать в `QTableWidget` динамическое изменение размеров ячеек при изменении размеров окна?
2. Как в `QGridLayout` реализовать пропорциональное изменение размеров `QTextEdit`?
3. Если ничего из предыдущих вариантов невозможно, то в каком направлении искать написание нового класса?

Comment: используй `QGridLayout`, только те два `QTextEdit`'а запихни в отдельный QHBoxLayout, чтобы во всех столбцах было одинаковое количество аргументов...

Comment: @Fat-Zer мда, а ответ был так близко.. Большое спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> void QGridLayout::setColumnStretch(int column, int stretch)
>
> Устанавливает коэффициент растяжения столбца для растяжения. Первый столбец - номер 0.

Больше ... https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(465, 168)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.textEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_11.setText("TEXT 11")
        self.textEdit_11.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(214, 0))
        self.textEdit_11.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 80))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_11, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        self.textEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_12.setText("TEXT")
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit_12.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit_12.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textEdit_12.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 80))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_12, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.textEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_13.setText("TEXT 13")
        
        self.textEdit_13.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(214, 0))               # +++

        self.textEdit_13.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_13, 0, 2, 1, 2)
        self.textEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_14.setText("111")
        self.textEdit_14.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_14, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        self.textEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_9.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_9.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(214, 0))
        self.textEdit_9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 80))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_9, 2, 0, 2, 1)
        self.textEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_7.setText("TEXT")
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit_7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit_7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textEdit_7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 80))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_7, 2, 1, 2, 1)
        self.textEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_8.setText("TEXT")
        self.textEdit_8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_8, 2, 2, 1, 2)
        self.textEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_10.setText("111")
        self.textEdit_10.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_10, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.textEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_15.setText("111")
        self.textEdit_15.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_15, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        
        
class Demo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 2)                                    # +++
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 0)                                    # +++
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)                                    # +++
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)                                    # +++        
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wtch = Demo()
    wtch.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]